# Control JPlayer from iframe

Tags: jquery, jplayer

I'm trying to pause my JPlayer playing an audio from inside my iframe.

I tried to use this code

```
$('#jquery_jplayer_1', window.parent.document).jPlayer('pause', 0);
```

It doesn't seems to work. Please help...